# Why I can't click the sliders?

Tags: python, slider, pygame-widgets

I created a pygame code to simulate Turing Patterns. I wanted to add sliders to update the variables while the simulation working but they don't work at all. When I click the screen it freezes and doesn't respond.

```
pygame.init()
w_width = 600
w_height = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([w_width, w_height])

ra = 3
ri = 5
wa = 1
wi = 0.2

screen.fill((128, 128, 128))
model = Model(rows,cols, ra, ri, wa, wi, 0.5)
model.drawGrid(screen, w_width, w_height)

slider_wa = Slider(screen, 40, 20, 50, 10, min=0, max=2, step=0.1)
output_wa = TextBox(screen, 5, 10, 25, 25, fontSize=15)
output_wa.disable()

slider_wi = Slider(screen, 140, 20, 50, 10, min=0, max=2, step=0.1)
output_wi = TextBox(screen, 105, 10, 25, 25, fontSize=15)
output_wi.disable()  

slider_ra = Slider(screen, 250, 20, 50, 10, min=0, max=10, step=0.5)
output_ra = TextBox(screen, 215, 10, 25, 25, fontSize=15)
output_ra.disable()

slider_ri = Slider(screen, 360, 20, 50, 10, min=0, max=10, step=0.5)
output_ri = TextBox(screen, 325, 10, 25, 25, fontSize=15)
output_ri.disable()

ra = slider_ra.getValue()
ri = slider_ri.getValue()
wa = slider_wa.getValue()
wi = slider_wi.getValue()
    
running = True

time_delay = 100
timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, time_delay )

win = pygame.display.set_mode([w_width, w_height])

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():   
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                model.update()
                model.drawGrid(screen, w_width, w_height)
        if event.type == timer_event:
                model.update()
                model.drawGrid(screen, w_width, w_height)
                
    
    screen.fill((128, 128, 128))
                
    output_wa.setText(slider_wa.getValue())
    output_wi.setText(slider_wi.getValue())
    output_ra.setText(slider_ra.getValue())
    output_ri.setText(slider_ri.getValue())
    
    pygame_widgets.update(event)
    pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
```

I tried the code I got from pygame documentation( [text](https://pygamewidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/widgets/slider/))  it is working well alone but I couldn't integrate it into my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the list of events to `pygame_widgets.update`, but not a single event (see also [Pygame Widgets](https://github.com/AustL/PygameWidgets#pygame-widgets). Calling `pygame_widget` outside the event loop with `event` does not do what you expect, because `event` always contains only the last event object in the queue, and thus not all events are passed to `pygame_widget`:

```py
while running:

    # get list of events
    events = pygame.event.get()
    
    # use the list of events in the event loop
    for event in events:   
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        # [...]

    # pass list of events to pygame widgets
    pygame_widgets.update(events)


    # [...]
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code has several issues that may be contributing to the freezing problem:

Multiple pygame.display.set_mode() Calls: You have initialized two screens (screen and win). You only need one.

Event Handling: The sliders need to be updated based on events, and it seems like you're using pygame_widgets for sliders, but you're not handling events for them in your event loop.

Repeated screen.fill(): You're filling the screen with a color after the model updates, which will erase everything. This means that even if the sliders were working, you wouldn't see them.

Updating Variables: You're setting ra, ri, wa, and wi before the game loop, but you're not updating the model with these values inside the loop.

Here's a refactored version of your code that addresses these issues:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame_widgets
from pygame_widgets import Slider, TextBox

# ... [assuming Model class and other necessary imports are above]

pygame.init()
w_width = 600
w_height = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([w_width, w_height])

ra = 3
ri = 5
wa = 1
wi = 0.2

model = Model(rows,cols, ra, ri, wa, wi, 0.5)
model.drawGrid(screen, w_width, w_height)

slider_wa = Slider(screen, 40, 20, 50, 10, min=0, max=2, step=0.1)
output_wa = TextBox(screen, 5, 10, 25, 25, fontSize=15)
output_wa.disable()

# ... [other sliders and text boxes]

ra = slider_ra.getValue()
ri = slider_ri.getValue()
wa = slider_wa.getValue()
wi = slider_wi.getValue()
    
running = True

time_delay = 100
timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, time_delay )

while running:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                model.update()
                model.drawGrid(screen, w_width, w_height)
        if event.type == timer_event:
                model.update()
                model.drawGrid(screen, w_width, w_height)

        # Update the sliders and text boxes with the current event
        pygame_widgets.update(events)
    
    # Only fill the part of the screen where the model is drawn
    # screen.fill((128, 128, 128), rect=pygame.Rect(0, 50, w_width, w_height-50))
                
    output_wa.setText(str(slider_wa.getValue()))
    output_wi.setText(str(slider_wi.getValue()))
    output_ra.setText(str(slider_ra.getValue()))
    output_ri.setText(str(slider_ri.getValue()))

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Calling `pygame_widgets.update(events)` in the event loop causes the list of events to be passed to `pygame_widgets` multiple times, which is just wrong.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?